# Java - Handling Listeners

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm relatively new to graphical user interfaces and I've created an interface that implements the functionality of a basic calculator. These methods include: add(), subtract(), multiply(), and divide(). I'm getting an error within my actionPerformed method that's saying "the method add(int, int) in the type Operate is not applicable for the arguments (int)." I've tried including the variables I've passed into my public class Operate and I still receive this error. How can I resolve this?

Here's my code for this method:

```
JButton btnNewButton_10 = new JButton("+");
btnNewButton_10.setFont(new Font("Helvetica Neue", Font.PLAIN, 15));
btnNewButton_10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int myFunction = calculate.add(Integer.parseInt(textDisplay.getText())); // The error is specifically underlining the keyword "add"
        textDisplay.setText("");
```

Comment: well it's kinda obvious... it underlined `add` and you only put one number!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to `add` 1 `int`, apparently your add function wants to `add` two `int`s together.

Comment: Okay, in my public class I have two variables being added. How can I account two ints for this within the actionPerformed method?

Comment: Right now you are using the correct method, you just only have one provided it with one `int` as a parameter, you need to do something like: `int myFunction = calculate.add(Integer.parseInt(textDisplay.getTest()), yourOtherInteger);` Where `yourOtherInteger` is the second variable you want to add.

Comment: My variables passed into the method add are variableA and variable B. Are you referring to other variable in the method add? I appreciate the help as well.

Comment: Right now you are using what looks to be an integer from a text box on your GUI, you are converting its string text to an integer, but you haven't added it to anything. If there is another text box on your form that you want to use to add the numbers together with (say called textDisplay2) then do `int myFunction = calculate.add(Integer.parseInt(textDisplay.getTest()), Integer.parseInt(` **textDisplay2** `.getTest()));`

Answer (score 2):

Ìt seems your `add` method takes 2 int arguments but you have only passed in one.

You need something like this instead:

```
int myFunction = calculate.add(Integer.parseInt(textDisplay.getText()), myOtherIntNumber);
```